# How to create listview with swipe delete functionality in xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, swipe-gesture

How to create a listview with swipe delete functionality with out SwipeView control in xamarin forms.
I want a listview page with swipe delete, if the cell item status is "pending", when user swipe the cell  to right need to display a delete icon in the listview. I got the same using swipeview control, but that control is "experimental". Is there any other solution for the same. please help on this.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity#context-actions

Comment: I need the delete icon in the cell instead of top of listview

Comment: then use SwipeView

Comment: We are using SwipeView in our projects in my company for a while and we haven't had any issues in production.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround via `SwipeGestureRecognizer`. As to "delete icon", you can use a custom Button instead and set its "IsVisible" to "false" to hide it.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Label Text="{Binding Name}"
        FontAttributes="Bold" />
<Button x:Name="buttontest"
        HorizontalOptions="End"
        HeightRequest="10"
        WidthRequest="60"
        BackgroundColor="Red"
        CornerRadius="20"
        Text="Del"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Clicked="Button_Clicked"
        IsVisible="false"/>
</Grid>
```

Add a SwipeGestureRecognizer to the Grid in ViewCell.

```
<Grid.GestureRecognizers>
    <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Right" Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_Swiped" />
</Grid.GestureRecognizers>
```

If swipe, show the button.

```
private void SwipeGestureRecognizer_Swiped(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (sender as Grid).Children.FirstOrDefault(c => Grid.GetRow(c) == 0 && Grid.GetColumn(c) == 1) as Button;
    button.IsVisible = true;
}
```

If the button clicked, hide the button.

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // hide button
    (sender as Button).IsVisible = false;
    // some other operations
}
```